# How to resize objects inside form to fit when you maximize the form

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to build a windows form application and I want the user to have the ability to play it in full-screen. When I press the full-screen button though it only put the buttons, etc. in the left corner, even if it was originally in the center of the normal size form.

I hope to resize all the objects in the form to be able to maximize. So if the button, for example, was in the middle of the normal sized form, it would be in the middle when you maximize the form.

Comment: change the control Anchor property

Comment: @Slai How do I then make the size proportional to the form as well. For example, if the size of the button was 60,60 for a 500,500 form, how do I then make it that proportioned to the maximized form.

Comment: programatically on resize event, or you can try the TableLayoutPanel control